# WSJT-X V2: How to identify stations already logged?

Tags: digital-modes, software, ft8

In V1.9 of WSJT-X, there was a feature that allowed one to change the color of stations already logged. This was necessary in knowing whether or not to respond to a given CQ.

In version 2, I am unable to determine whether or not I have already logged a potential contact that is calling CQ.

Is there a way to have WSJT-X V2 signify whether or not one has logged a given call sign?

Comment: According to the FT8 Operating Guide (https://www.physics.princeton.edu/pulsar/K1JT/FT8_Operating_Tips.pdf) there is a 3rd party software, JTAlert (http://www.hamapps.com/) which does this.  Not tried it myself, though.

Comment: is there any way to revert a call sign to a new call? i had someone reject a qso and id like him to appear as a new call again in wsjt-x

Answer (score 3):

Set your "New Call" to one color and your "CQ in message" to a different color. My new call CQs are green and my "CQ in message" are light red. The light red indicates that I have worked the station before because it is not a "New Call". And as Chris said, JTAlert also works.

The logic is that the combination of "New Call" and "CQ Only" result in New Call CQs and anything left over from that having "CQ in Message" is not a New Call. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I read through the manual and didn't find the answer. I thought it had been left out of the software. FT8 Is much more fun now that I can identify stations I've already contacted.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip on setting "New call and "CQ only. That did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

I have version 2.1.0.  Under File->Settings, select the General tab. There is a box marked "Show DXCC, grid, and worked before status" that can be check marked.  I use that to identify stations I have worked before.